# How do I find the general solution for this ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x^2+1)(y^2-1)\,\mathrm dx + xy \,\mathrm dy = 0$$

The answer is said to be $\frac{x+y}{1-xy} = \tan(c)$

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will edit my post..

Comment: That "answer" looks suspiciously fishy, and that $\;\tan c\;$  looks really weird. Where did you get the answer from?

Comment: It was provided in the textbook it self ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You can rearrange the equation to the form $$\frac{x^2+1}x\mathrm dx=\frac y{1-y^2}\mathrm dy$$Then you can integrate both sides. From here, we get 
$$\frac12 x^2+\ln x+\frac12\ln(1-y^2)=C\\e^{x^2}x^2(1-y^2)=e^{2C}\equiv c\\y^2=1-\frac c{x^2 e^{x^2}}\\y=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-ce^{-x^2}}}{x}$$This is the general solution.

---

Also note: 
$$\frac{x+y}{1-xy}=\frac{x^2+\sqrt{x^2-ce^{-x^2}}}{x}\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{x^2-ce^{-x^2}}}=\frac{2x^2-ce^{-x^2}+(1+x^2)\sqrt{x^2-ce^{-x^2}}}{x(1-x^2+ce^{-x^2})}$$This doesn't appear to cancel down to a constant in any obvious way.

Comment: Yes my problem is getting from 1/2 ln([y^2]-1) = -[(x^2)/2] -ln(x)+c to the actual desired solution

Comment: @Steward Exactly my point in my past comment: where do you get $\;\tan C\;$ from? What is $\;C\;$ , anyway?! And after applying the exponential there are still things like $\;e^{x^2/2}\;$ ...

Comment: @Steward Hmm, yes I see the problem now. I don't believe that answer is correct.

Comment: In that case, what would be the correct answer ?

Comment: @Steward see the edit.

Comment: Okay, thank you for all the help (: